# Store image on Firebase not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to upload an image onto Firebase Storage. Currently, the image is uploading as I can download it from the Firebase console, however it is not letting me continue inside the closure. I am unsure if this is a basic Firebase misunderstanding or iOS. Let me know if I can provide more information.

```
    var storageRef : FIRStorageReference = FIRStorageReference()
    if let num = num {
        storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(num).png")
    }

    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePictureImageView.image!) {
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/png"
        print("ABOUT TO STORAGE \(uploadData)")
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: metadata).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
            print("IN STORAGE")
            let text = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        }
    }
```

The only print out I am getting when I debug is

> ABOUT TO STORAGE 8663314 bytes

EDIT: 
In the past, I have also tried solving this problem by doing:

```
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePictureImageView.image!) {
        print("IN UPLOAD DATA \(uploadData)")
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: metadata) { [weak self] (metadata,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR \(error)")
                return
            } else {
                print("NO ERROR")
            }

            if let profileImageURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                self?.profilePicURL = profileImageURL
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, I do not get past the "IN UPLOAD DATA" print statement.

Comment: Well, there is clearly some error going on. How about observing something else as well and not only `.success`? Let's see what you get in the console then.

Comment: With    .failure  and .pause I am still seeing nothing. Should I try something else?

Comment: Where is this code called? Is it in some ephemeral object that gets destroyed right after this method has been called? You should see some sort of output in one of those methods (`.success`/`.failure`), unless the method `put` doesn't get executed at all.

Comment: @sschunara solved it below : it was just taking a lot longer to upload then I had expected. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your image is too big(8.66 MB). I suggest to use progress observe to know progress of upload data. Use below code.

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: metadata) { snapshot, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
    let downloadURL = snapshot!.downloadURL()
  }
}

uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
  // A progress event occurred track progress percentage here.
}
```